# Nhibernate many to many shared collection issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

structure:
TypeA has collection of TypeB and TypeB has collection of TypeC.

TypeB and TypeC are manytomany.

TypeA mapped

```
HasMany<TypeB>(t => t.TypeBList).CascadeAll().Inverse()..
```

TypeB mapped

```
HasManyToMany<TypeC>(t => t.TypeCList).Casecade.All().Inverse()..
```

TypeC mapped

```
HasManyToMany<TypeB>(t => t.TypeBList).Casecade.None()...
```

TypeB has a method to

```
Add(TypeC typec) { typec.TypeBList.Add(this); TypeBList.Add(typec); }
```

And I need to add a new typec to typeb collection, but 
I want to save by calling repo.Save(typeA) but I'm getting shared collection issue because TypeB exists in both TypeA and TypeC.

```
var typec = new TypeC { TypeBList = typea.TypeBList, .... }
typea.TypeBList[0].Add(typec);
repo.save(typea);
```

Will this not work by saving typea, am I forced to get a typeb and make the changes there?

Comment: I think I figured it out...rather than setting TypeC.TypeBList = typea.TypeBList I need to set it to a new separate list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collections on objects should generally not be shared at all and most of the time, especially when using NHibernate, you shouldn't even alter the collection instance. better copy the contents.

```
obj1.ListA.Clear();

foreach(var item in obj2.ListA)
    obj1.ListA.Add(Item);
```

Update: Why?

Because NHibernate replaces the collection instances with own collection classes to enable lazyloading and changetracking.